# Difference between IABHelper and IInAppBillingService in InAPPBilling

Tags: android, in-app-billing

In the google document for InAppBilling V3 they used IInAppBillingService to make purchases . check the below URL.

http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html

Bundle buyIntentBundle = mService.getBuyIntent(3, getPackageName(),
sku, "inapp", "bGoa+V7g/yqDXvKRqq+JTFn4uQZbPiQJo4pf9RzJ");

But in the Trivial Example coming along with SDK, they used IABHelper to make purchases.

I am having confusion like whether IABHelper is V2 and IInAppBillingService is V3.

because u cant get the available SKU Details through IABHelper . but through IInAppBillingService , it is possible

Bundle skuDetails = mService.getSkuDetails(3, 
getPackageName(), "inapp", querySkus);

which one is most current version ?.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`IABHelper` is just a wrapper utility class, which intends to give you an example of how `IInAppBillingService` is to be used.

`IInAppBillingService` is a part of in-app billing API. It is used to perform purchases and check statuses. You can use this service directly and forget about the helper class.

Many people find `IABHelper` simpler and they use it as-is. Other people use service and ignore helper class completely.

Comment: IABHelper is great and easy. The only BUG that it has is when a refund is done. The product is seen as Purchased even is Refunded. Checked even after couple of days. Bug is reported but no-one is fixing it. https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3/issues/435