# Android in app billing approaches

Tags: android

I've been looking at these resources:

- https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html
- https://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/index.html

They each show a different way to integrate billing.

The first one talks about binding to `IInAppBillingService` and using `ServiceConnection`, the second suggests everything can be done using `IabHelper`.

Which article is correct? Or if they both do the same thing, which one is generally thought to be the better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is a duplicate of this question which explains the difference between the two.

[Difference between IABHelper and IInAppBillingService in InAPPBilling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24106255/difference-between-iabhelper-and-iinappbillingservice-in-inappbilling)

In short, `IabHelper` wraps the `IInAppBillingService` code to make your life easier.