# What is IABHelper?

Tags: android, in-app-billing

Could someone leave the main difference between In-App-Billing Helper (IABHelper) and In-App-Billing (IAB)?

And does IABHelper still required these days?

Sorry if there is anything not clear but I'm new to In-App-Billing.

> I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24106255/difference-between-iabhelper-and-iinappbillingservice-in-inappbilling) but I think It's so old and maybe there are any updates.

Comment: They`re kind of old stuff to deal with in-app purchases. Consider taking a look at Google Play Billing Library instead of those classes. Link: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate

Comment: @AugustoCarmo should I add AIDL in my app?

Comment: No AIDL implementation is needed when using that library.